# How to send notifications to users when a message is posted in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, android-notifications

I wanted to send notification to users as soon as a message is posted by the admin.

What I'm facing currently:

- Every time I open the app, notification sound arrives even though there are no new messages ( Is it because the code is written in `onCreate()` method?)
- When I click on the notification, I'm redirected to the `MainActivity` correctly and again the notification sound comes. Its kind of annoying :(

I wrote the Notification code in `addChildEventListener`. Can anyone guide me in fixing the above mentioned things. Please review my following code.

Code for `MainActivity` of my app.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    // [Start of onCreate Method]
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        // NOTIFICATIONS
        mBuilder =
                (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bcm_logo)
                        .setContentTitle("BCM")
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setContentText("You have a new message")
                        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification when clicked

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);

        messagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Child ADDED !");

                Log.d(TAG, "D: " + dataSnapshot);

                    mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Child Changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CHILD REMOVED!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Child Moved");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Child Cancelled");
            }
        });
    }    // [End of onCreate Method]


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Log.d(TAG, "User Signed in");

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                finish();
            }

        } 
    }

    ...

    // WHAT IF SIGNED IN
    private void onSignedInitialize(String userDisplayName) {
        mUserName = userDisplayName;
        Message.setSenderName(mUserName);
        attachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    // ATTACH AND DETACH THE DATABASE READ LISTENERS
    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (childEventListener == null) {
            childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(message);
                }

                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };
            messagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        }
    }
    ...
} // [END of Main Activity]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here is that onChildAdded() will be called with every single Message from your Database as soon as you attach the Listener to your DatabaseReference. As there is no start or end of the Datastream from your Database there is no way to determine when an Message is "new" and when to show a notification. There are two possible Solutions:

`1.` Use a ValueEventListener:

```
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            Boolean showNotification = false;

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(showNotification) {
                    mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
                }
                //use your Data here
                showNotification = true;  
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The downside of this approach is that you will get the whole list of Messages everytime there is a new Message.

`2.` Use a Timestamp in your data structure:
Save the Timestamp of Creation inside your Message.
Then you can extend your existing ChildEventListener like this:

```
messagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(
new ChildEventListener() {

    //set to the time when the listener is created
    private long attachTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Child ADDED !");
        Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
        //if the message is newer then then the creation of the ChildEventListener -> show notification
        if(message.getCreationTime > attachTime) {
            mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
            attachTime = message.getCreationTime;
        }
        //use your Data here
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Child Changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CHILD REMOVED!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Child Moved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Child Cancelled");
    }
});
```

**Full Example:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "MessagesActivity";
    private static final int mNotificationId = 1;
    private DatabaseReference messagesDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bcm_logo)
                        .setContentTitle("BCM")
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setContentText("You have a new message")
                        .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification when clicked

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        messagesDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        attachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (childEventListener == null) {
            childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Child ADDED !");
                    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                    //if the message is newer then then the creation of the ChildEventListener -> show notification
                    if(message.getCreationTime > attachTime) {
                        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

                    }
                    mMessageAdapter.add(message);
                }

                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                }

                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            };
            messagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
        }
    }

    private void detachDatabaseReadListener() {
        messagesDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(childEventListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, It didn't work out :( In 2nd case, the message.getCreationTime() is always >= attach time. Hence, it isn't working. Need your guidance! In my **LogCat**: `In Model TIME IN MS : 1499297543427 ; Attach time in MS: 1499297696644`

Comment: It didn't work! what data you are referring to ? about this line `//use your Data here`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide more detailed information on what is not working. You could for example replace the comment with your Code: `mMessageAdapter.add(message);`

Comment: Where do I need to put this? In `onCreate` method or in the `attachDatabaseReadListener` ? Need help.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Keep in mind that the listener is bound to the activity lifecycle, so it will stop receiving new messages as soon as the activity is closed. If you also want to receive new messages when your app is closed consider using a service. If you have questions regarding this please open another question. It would be nice if you could accept my answer!